# Duplicate each row as many times as is given in a variable

Tags: stata

I have a set of individuals with characteristics. Each individual belongs to one or more group. I need to merge individuals to group characteristics, by firstly duplicating each row of individual data set as many times as is given by `n_groups`.

The data looks like

```
id  age  n_groups
1   50  2
2   46  1
3   51  3
4   44  2
```

I need to have

```
id  age n_groups group_index
1   50  2   1
1   50  2   2
2   46  1   1
3   51  3   1
3   51  3   2
3   51  3   3
4   44  2   1
4   44  2   1
```

It seems like a very easy task, and I need some variation of `expand` with variable number of duplicates. Any ideas if there is a simple command for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1358759-duplicate-each-row-as-many-times-as-is-given-in-a-variable where there are solutions. Telling people about cross-posting in other forums is widely regarded as polite.

Comment: thank you, @Nick, will do that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Appears the solution is very standard. The `expand` command indeed allows for expanding based on variable: `expand n_groups` solved the question.

Comment: Not quite, because your extra variable needs to be created.